# Перенос строки в PHP

Tags: php

Господа, не работает перенос строки в php модуле mail. Он тупо пишет в одну строчку, выдавая тег переноса в теле письма. Что я делаю не так?

Вот что приходит в теле письма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код модуля:

```
<?php

$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Письмо с сайта';

$message = 'Пользователь ' .$_POST['name']. ' отправил Вам письмо:<br/>'. $_POST['message'] . '<br/>С ним можно связаться
по email: ' . $_POST['email'];

//$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message);
?>
```

Comment: а зачем вы закоментировали строку "Content-type: text/html " ?? может именно в нём ваше спасение? чтобы php mail понимал HTML теги

Answer (score 1):

Или это у вас html:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           // указываем, что это html, а не plain text
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";//кодировку указать нужную

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );//$headers не забыть добавить
```

Если нет, тогда пишите `\r\n` а не `<br>`